# Is there a way to scale icons in the launcher smaller than 32 pixels?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I am using 11.10 beta and want to give Unity another chance (I was always very fond of XFCE) ... anyway is there a way to scale the Icons to a really small size, let's say ~25?? And can this also be done for unity-2d, I figure the Compiz configuration tool won't work with Unity-2D?